# Is it wrong to use EventBus with Android Gatt callbacks?

Tags: android

I am writing an android app in native that uses ble. Was looking into using the gatt, but got stuck due to how the gatt callbacks were implemented.

So I was planning on using the Eventbus (For those who will recommend me using rx, personally I agree but I can't for other reasons on this project) to basically "reroute" the callbacks because I need a variety of behaviors on the gatt callbacks that implementing them all in the same call back would create a huge nightmare (strong coupling, unreadable code, etc). Am I doing something absolutely wrong?

Just for reference I am leaving a sample code:

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    Eventbus.getDefault().post(CallbackEvent("write");
}
```

and idea being I would subscribe to above event for wherever I need it.

Environment is android api23 with minimumsdk 21+

also this is my first post so any comments or feedback appreciated. Thanks!